# How to pass POST value to Slimframe work page in php

Tags: php, html, slim-3

I need to pass HTML form fields using POST method to Slim framework in php. please help.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php file

1. Initialize the Function and Route url

   ```
   $app->post('/xyz/routename', 'functionname');
   ```
2. Create function

   ```
   function functionname()
   {
       $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
       $credentials = $app->request->post();
   }
   ```

All Input field value available in $credentials object.

Comment: Sujal Patel, I'll check it sir.

Comment: Hi Sujal Patel,  Which file i have to Initialize the Function and Route url (that Form page or Slim page) .

Comment: main route file index.php

Comment: oh sir i'll try to implement.

Comment: not showing any error sir. Actually I need form fields pass to slim page and insert to Database please give and post example code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$this->app = new \Slim\Slim();

$this->app->post("/post/create", function () {

    $userId = $this->app->request->post('user');

    // or

    $allPostVars = $this->app->request->post();
    $userId = $allPostVars['user'];
    //...

});
```

if you dont want to use anonymous function ("*It is not possible to use $this from anonymous function before PHP 5.4.0*"), i think you can just do:

```
$this->app->post("/post/create", 'createPost');


function createPost() {
        $userId = $this->app->request->post('user');
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->post('/api/v1/customers/new', function (Request $request, Response 
$response) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $ticket_data = [];
    $ticket_data['name'] = filter_var($data['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ticket_data['age'] = filter_var($data['age'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $response->getBody()->write(var_export($ticket_data, true));
    return $response;
});
```

i just tried with following it worked for me.

the post body for the above API has 2 parameters i.e name and age. return the response to see the sent values.

```
[please follow this tutorial for better understanding][1]

  [1]: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html
```